# Edit rails gem without restarting server

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, refresh

Rails3:
I cloned an existing gem in order to modify it in development.
I put in my gemfile:

gem 'my_gem_name', :path => '../gems/my_gem_name'

It's working fine, but every time I want to edit the gem, I have to restart my rails server.
Is there a way that I don't need to restart the server?

For view/controller/helper files there is the setting `config.cache_classes = false` but I wasn't able to find a similar one for the locals gem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few other questions along the same lines with mixed results:

[One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191635/how-to-reload-a-gem-on-every-request-in-development-mode)
[Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418895/how-to-reload-all-gems-in-rails-3)
[Three](http://blog.givmo.com/2011/06/how-to-reload-gems-that-youre-working-on/)

Comment: I totally understand. Sometimes I have to ask someone "what do I google?" rather than specific help.

Comment: Third link is now broken.